# Changing PS1 and PS2 depending upon outcome of previous command?

Tags: bash, shell

I am maintaining some shell scripts and one of the them (bash_profile.sh) has the following function defined.

I don't quiet get what the purpose of this function is.

```
alias scpresume = "rsync --partial --progress --rsh=ssh

function exitstatus {
    EXITSTATUS="$?"
    BOLD="\[\033[1m\]"
    RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
    GREEN="\[\e[32;1m\]"
    BLUE="\[\e[34;1m\]"
    OFF="\[\033[m\]"

    PROMPT="${GREEN}\u@\h:${BLUE}\w${OFF}\n$"

    if [ "${EXITSTATUS}" -eq 0 ]
    then
       PS1="${PROMPT}${BOLD}${GREEN}>${OFF} "
    else
       PS1="${PROMPT}${BOLD}${RED}>${OFF} "
    fi

    PS2="${BOLD}>${OFF} "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=exitstatus
```

Comment: That function is somewhat poorly written. The only reason to want to put those variable lines into the function itself would be to keep them local (so they aren't globally available) but the function doesn't do that. The function also duplicates more than it needs to when setting `PS1` and needlessly sets `PS2` after every command. That probably doesn't matter *in the slightest* in practice but is still awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the previous command was successful (exit status 0), the prompt would show a green `>`, otherwise, the `>` will be red.

I use PROMPT_COMMAND in bash for the similar behaviour (showing the exit status, too):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='_e=$?; if (($_e)) ; then echo -e "\e[31;1m[$_e]\e[m" ; fi'
```

Comment: by previous command are we referring to the alias scpresume = "rsync --partial --progress --rsh=ssh   ?

Comment: @SMV: No. PROMPT_COMMAND is called after each command entered through the command line.

Comment: I am trying out your command.. what's    "\e[31;1m[$_e]\e[m"   I do understand that isntead of [m  i get [2 when the command fails

Comment: @SMV: The ANSI codes change the colour, so in my terminal, I see the exit code in red. Try running `(exit 5)` to get `[5]` etc.